# Life expectancy of fan with magnetic bearing?

Tags: fan, magnet

In my laptop, the only fan has magnetic bearing. I haven't seen much information about life expectancy of computer fans with magnetic bearing, so I'm asking you how long can I expect it to last?

I know that it should last longer than ball bearing  and much longer than sleeve bearing, but I'd like to see some comparison.

Comment: All of my magnetic fans that have died (two) were due to plastic around the center post cracking, causing the post to lean or even break off.

Answer (score 1):

They do tend to live longer than ball bearing but exact figure is hard to tell. I would say that it should last as your laptop (4-5 years). In theory it could live even longer.

As with standard (ball-bearing) fans it mostly depends on manufacturing quality. Higher quality ball-bearing will outlive (by huge margin) fan that is manufactured poorly (usually noname).

Good thing about magnetic bearing fans is that there isn't many no-name manufacturers.

Answer (score 1):

Ball bearing fans are typically rated at 130,000+ hours life, though some as short as 100,000.

If the bearing in your fan truly is superior to a ball bearing fan, it should last longer than 130,000 hours.

Comment: Well, the only friction comes from air and the bearing itself has no moving components, so I think that it's better than ball bearing. I did look at some magnetic bearing fans, but none have life expectancy information in specifications.

Answer (score 1):

bear in mind when it comes to fans their life expectancy is largely dependant on what air you put through it, otherwise dust and debris will clog it long before any bearing issues.

Comment: I do regular maintenance and remove dust and derbies as soon as visible amounts accumulate. +1 for derbies, though. Most dead fans I've seen come died from that cause.

Answer (score 1):

It will last longer than you will.

Comment: Any source for that? I spent some time looking and was unable to find any reference to how long magnetic bearing fans can last.

Comment: @Mark Johnson Yes and? More technically minded people there don't know it either or at least didn't when I posted the question.

Comment: @Mark Johnson Don't worry, I've already made arrangements in case something happens. Report will be made.